# How to show the current URL that webkit is on

Tags: swift, webkit

I want the current URL that webkit is on to show up in the address bar. I can't seem to figure out a solution.
As of right now all I have is a webkit that is taking the string from the text field to use as a url.
But I want it to display the current url everytime the url changes so for example if I am on youtube.com and I search "hello" it should display https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hello after.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, It's not possible with WebKit at this time, your best bet is `SFSafariController`

```
 import SafariServices

 func open_web(url:string) {
   let urlTallerWeb = URL(string: url)
   let vistaTalleres = SFSafariViewController(url: urlTallerWeb!)
   present(vistaTalleres, animated: true, completion: nil)
   vistaTalleres.delegate = self as? SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
 }
```